# Fail on a dependency conflict for a specific dependency group

Tags: android, gradle

I want to verify that specific dependencies of my Android app don't have a conflict, therefore there is only one version of them in a Gradle tree.

In other words, I'd like to achieve the same behaviour as Gradle instruction

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        failOnVersionConflict()
    }
}
```

but only for some specific groups, because `failOnVersionConflict` strategy causes too much overhead and in most cases the default resolution strategy does its job well.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I implemented the following method, which takes a set of target groups, goes through a set of dependencies, matches them if they are from target groups and throws an error if a version conflict is found:

```
void failOnVersionConflictForGroups(Object groups) {
    def encounteredVersions = [:]

    configurations.configureEach {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            // Determine if the current dependency's group is in the specified groups
            boolean isInSpecifiedGroups = groups instanceof String ? details.requested.group == groups : groups.contains(details.requested.group)

            if (isInSpecifiedGroups) {
                // Check if we have already encountered a version for this group
                if (encounteredVersions.containsKey(details.requested.group)) {
                    // If the version is different from the one already encountered, consider it a conflict
                    if (encounteredVersions[details.requested.group] != details.requested.version) {
                        throw new GradleException("Version conflict detected within group '${details.requested.group}'. " +
                                "Encountered versions: ${encounteredVersions[details.requested.group]} and ${details.requested.version}.")
                    }
                } else {
                    // If this is the first version encountered for this group, record it
                    encounteredVersions[details.requested.group] = details.requested.version
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming the target dependency looks like `com.example.test:dependency:x.y.z`,
declare this method and call it on the top level of an app's `build.gradle` file:

```
failOnVersionConflictForGroups('com.example.test')
```

That command guarantees, that all the dependencies of `com.example.test` group have the same version.
For example, if gradle tree contains dependencies
`com.example.test:dependency1:1.0.0`, `com.example.test:dependency2:1.0.1`, an error will be thrown:

```
Unresolved dependencies

Version conflict detected within group 'com.example.test'. Encountered versions: 1.0.0 and 1.0.1.
```